# Mapping Depth onto RGB Kinect using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imageview, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to map the Depth map onto the RGB image on the Kinec using MATLAB.
So here are the steps that I took:
(1) Obtain the images using a C++ program.
(2) Using the depth value from each pixel on MATLAB, I was able to obtain the XYZ distances of all the pixels in mm.
(3) Then using some equations, I was able to obtain the XY pixel coordinates of those depth pixels on the RGB image.

So I am left with a huge cell containing all the locations of the depth map w.r.t the color image.

So my question is now if I want to overlay the depth image on the color image, how can I do that?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks;